# LINQ return type issues for sending eMail in C#

Tags: c#, linq, email

I am a newer developer and am trying to get a better grasp on LINQ.  I am trying to get a string from the web.config of MailingAddresses and split the string on ";" or "," characters and then add each of these addresses to a collection of mailing addresses, but I'm running into a couple of issues.

**Relevant Code**

```
    var emailTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["eROCSendTo"];
    IEnumerable<MailAddress> mailAddresses = emailTo.Select(x => x.ToString().Split(new string[] {";", ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Select(y => new MailAddress(y.ToString().Trim()));

    mail.To.Add(mailAddresses);
```

What I've noticed is that if I try to initialize `mailAddresses` to the `MailMessage.To` property, the signature wants a string or a MailAddress item.  Am I going about this completely wrong or am I remotely close to getting the code to compile?

I was hoping to learn something new with LINQ and while simultaneously avoiding a bunch of foreach loops in my code.  If it helps, this is the full method currently.

**SendMail Method**

```
public static void SendMail(String Message)
    {
        using (var mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            var emailTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["eROCSendTo"];
            IEnumerable<MailAddress> mailAddresses = emailTo.Select(x => x.ToString().Split(new string[] {";", ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Select(y => new MailAddress(y.ToString().Trim()));

            mail.To.Add(mailAddresses);
            mail.From = new MailAddress("info@test.com");
            mail.Body = Message;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
            mail.Subject = "New Contact Form Submitted";

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please feel free to critique anything else in my code as my primary goal is to get better and conform to the communities "best standards".

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you facing a compiler error? If yes, then state what it says.

Comment: The current issue is that on this line : `mail.To.Add(mailAddresses)`, it says `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.MailAddressCollection.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mail.To.Add` expect a single address because `To` [implements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection(v=vs.110).aspx) `Collection<MailAddress>` and uses [Collection.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Then to add all addresses just enumerate it and add each to collection:

```
foreach(var address in mailAddresses)
{
    mail.To.Add(address);
}
```

For clearly LINQ solution you can use next code:

```
emailTo.Select(x => x.ToString().Split(new string[] {";", ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Select(y => new MailAddress(y.ToString().Trim())).ToList().ForEach(mail.To.Add);
```

but it will cause a memory allocation for new `List<T>` in method `ToList()`. To avoid this you can add LINQ query inside foreach loop (but now your code will be less readable):

```
foreach(var address in emailTo.Select(x => x.ToString().Split(new string[] {";", ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Select(y => new MailAddress(y.ToString().Trim()))) 
{ 
    mail.To.Add(address); 
}
```

Comment: I probably should have been more clear in my question .. for my own learning advantages, is it possible to do that foreach in LINQ?

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much.  Would you mind editing your original answer to also include this LINQ code for anyone else who comes across this answer?

Comment: Is that last answer the most preferable one because it doesn't allocate memory for a new List<T> ?

Comment: I think that the most preferable is my first code with separated variable and loop. It's because LINQ query don't evaluate immediately and allocate memory for result. You can read more about [Deferred Execution on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx)

Comment: @user3267755 FYI, first `List<T>.ForEach` is not LINQ, but `List<T>` method. and second, most of the LINQ methods are implemented with `foreach` inside. You'd better learn how to **build** LINQ **queries**, not how to consume them (`foreach` was and still is the primary way of consuming `IEnumerable<T>`). Using `ToList`/`ToArray`/`ToWhatever` just to get access to a fancy method makes your code inefficient, with absolutely no any benefit.  Read the last Vadim's comment, there are quite good point there. Vadim, +1 of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not have noticed that emailTo is a string variable

```
        string emailTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["eROCSendTo"];
```

and so `emailTo.Select(x => ...)` will iterate over *every character of the string* - (and you call `ToString().Split()' on the character, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need to split it all when the method allows you to pass an string with multiple email addresses(separating by `,`):

```
abc@example.com,asd@example.com
```

Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can just replace all `;` with `,`:

```
var emailTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["eROCSendTo"].Replace(';', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since To.Add only accept `MailAddress` instead of collection so you can either change your linq query to iterate over and add the item in query itself

```
emailTo.Select(x => x.ToString().Split(new string[] {";", ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Select(y => new MailAddress(y.ToString().Trim())).ToList().ForEach(t =>  mail.To.Add(t));
```

Or you can write an extension for `MailAddressCollection` for `AddRange` as shown below

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> target, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            target.Add(item);
        }   
    }
}
```

And now use it as

```
mail.To.AddRange(mailAddresses);
```